# Recognize an entity changed anywhere in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a restart function for users with admin rights every time the data in the Setting Table is changed. Currently, I deploy via socket and every time the api makes data changes in the Setting Table, I send a restartable message and show the restart button to the admin users.

There are only a few APIs available at the moment so control is still easy, the application can grow and controlling those APIs that affect the Setting entity will be a problem.

I would like to ask if there is a general way we can know that Setting Entity is changed and send message via socket there.

Comment: The answer is yes.